# Architecture of a Spring MVC application with AJAX / JSON / REST

Tags: java, ajax, json, rest, spring-mvc

First, I developed a Java EE application with a Adobe Flex frontend and I used BlazeDS.
So I had in the Java backend this structure:

IServiceX -> ServiceImplX -> IDaoX -> DaoImplX

So the frontend called a service like "addUser(User u)". The service implementation calls the Dao interface which implements a Dao to a database and the User is added. The return value is the new User ID.

Now I want to use instead of Adobe Flex HTML5 with AJAX. So I found this example project:
https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/mvc-ajax/

I have the problem how to integrate this into my existing architecture.
In this case I have a domain object called Account.java and a controller AccountController.java: 
https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/mvc-ajax/trunk/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/mvc/ajax/account/AccountController.java

Is it okay to create a Controller and this controller calls the already existing services?
Or should I update/change my architecture (but I do not know how...)?

Thank you in advance & Best Regards.

Comment: I assume you're using Spring 3?

Comment: Yes, right, the latest Spring version 3.0.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right - simply create a `XController`, annotated with `@Controller` and inject your existing service there. Take a look at [Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) docs. Also check the [ajax simplifications article](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/) for spring mvc 3.0

Comment: Yes, I already read all these docs, but there were no answers to my questions about architecture, services and dao pattern. One more thing: One controller per view, right? Because I have a view in which three domain objects are involved (User, Projects, Addresses). So I create one controller which will handle these accessing them through the services.

Comment: @Tim - I confirmed that you don't have to change your existing structure, you just have to create a controller. As of whether to use one controller per view - it's a matter of preference.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest "one controller per view". For example, if you have a web interaction that involves your User, Projects, and Addresses, and you suddenly want to render the model using XML rather than HTML, does it make sense to create a new controller class? A lot simpler to either add some sort of `viewType` request parameter or to use content negotiation of the client's accept headers. Re-use code where you can, and make things like "which view to use" configurable.